# updating android simplecursoradapter cursor

Tags: android

I have an android list activity that is backed by a database cursor through a SimpleCursorAdapter.

i have one constraint that need to be modify the cursor data. i cannot add the constraint in query.

How should I be update cursor ?

Comment: Please post how you used and defined your cursor. You can edit the question and add the details.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot manually modify the contents of a `Cursor` obtained from a database query. You will need to read the data out of the `Cursor`, modify it per your "constraint", and then put the results in a `MatrixCursor` or an `ArrayList` of model objects or something.